# RGB image with depth info

Tags: rgb, labview, realsense

I am using the Intel ReslSense D435 stereo camera.
I need to get RGB image correlated with depth information. I am using the LabVIEW wrapper.

I succeed to grab depth info, grayscale image of the left camera and RGB image from the RGB camera. I didn't succeed to get RGB image from the left camera (the dll doesn't give me an option to do it).

The RGB image is not correlated with the depth info. How can I correlate between the RGB and the depth?

Comment: Please, post code examples, resulting information what you receive, etc. - that could help in solving of the issue. Because now there are more questions to your question, than answers... For example, what does it mean - "RGB image is not correlated with the depth info"? Why do you consider it; how it should be to be correlated with the depth info?

Answer (score 1):

The D435 has only 1 RGB camera and then 2 IR sensor (used for the depth), this is the reason why you cannot get the "option to do it".
In order to correlate images with depth you can take a look at this:

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/Projection-in-RealSense-SDK-2.0